# Best practice for returning objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

hope you're having a good day.

I'm making a simple node.js api, and I wondered which of these is the most performant way to return a response.

I use this class for returning responses:

```
class Response {
    constructor(statusCode, error, data){
        this.status = statusCode;
        this.error = error;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

export default const handleResponse =  (statusCode = 200, error = '', data = {}) => {
    return new HandlerResponse(statusCode, error, data);
}
```

Sometimes I use it this way:

```
const response = handleResponse();

if(condition) {
    response.error = 'An error ocurred';
    response.status = 400;
    return response;
} else {
    response.error = 'Some other error';
    response.status = 404;
    return response;
}
```

And sometimes I use it like this:

```
if(condition) {
    return handleResponse(400, 'An error ocurred')
} else return handleResponse(404, 'Some other error')
```

Would be a difference between this two in performance? Which should I use?

Comment: The only way to know which is faster would be to run some tests. However, I think you're optimising prematurely. I guess these API calls are happening at most a few times per second? Any performance gains will likely be minimal either way. What I'm saying is, don't worry about it.

Comment: Agreed. Object creation and property assignment are extremely fast. Unless you're calling these in a tight loop in framework code, the network overhead of your server would dwarf your response initialization.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment.  This is massively premature optimization.  Write the code in what seems like the cleanest, simplest and most maintainable way. Some time in the future if you have a specific performance issue, then set up test cases and instrumentation for the specific issue at hand to isolate where the actual bottleneck is.  It is almost never where you think it might be by code inspection.  In any regular web system, the primary bottleneck almost always involves storage of some type (database, file system, etc...) as that stuff is massively slower than a few lines of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fact that the first implementation is allocating memory, is the less performant solution of the two. However, performance gains would not be realized between either implementation because of how negligible they would be. Javascript, like most popular languages, is extremely performant and so most of the time it's best to focus on **readability** more than performance when it comes to determining the best implementation.

Comment: Both implementations allocate memory.

Comment: Yes, both of them allocate memory through the usage of `handleResonse`. My answer was directed at the two ways OP calls `handleResonse`, which is what they're questioning the performance on. The first way is allocating memory, while the second is not.

Comment: If you trace both pathways through, you'll see they both call the constructor. This is when memory will be allocated.

Answer (score 0):

### The two implementations are almost the same

Both do the following;

1. Allocate an object in memory
2. Add a numerical property to the object
3. Add a string to the object

The only practical difference between the two is that the first option also allocates an empty object if you leave that parameter unspecified, whereas the second leaves that field undefined.

### The only way to know which is faster is to test them both

To determine which of the two is faster, you would have to test them both. On one hand, the empty object (the optional "data" parameter) should theoretically slow the first implementation slightly. On the other hand, its possible the javascript engine might optimise the first one better because it doesn't have a branch in the middle.